# faster substring processing C++

Tags: c, string

I have a program which does some processing on all possible substrings of a certain length. I am trying to make the program as fast as possible. I am just wondering what could be done to the following program to make it more faster

```
char str[] = "abcdcddcdcdcdcd....................." // large string
int n = strlen(str), m = 20;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  char *substr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*m);
  strncpy(substr, str+i, m);
  // do some processing
  int h = hd(substr, X) // X is another string of same length
  free(substr); 
}

unsigned int hd(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{

    return std::inner_product(
        s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(),
        0, std::plus<unsigned int>(),
        std::not2(std::equal_to<std::string::value_type>())
    );
}
```

Comment: That's not c++ code. Looks more like plain c actually.

Comment: You can avoid the `malloc` call, and create your buffer outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes, I am using `char*` instead of `string`. I think `substr()` function of `string` creates an object. So it will be slower for big string.

Comment: By analysing the substring in place instead of copying it at all?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I would like to get rid of `malloc`. I also tried putting it before the loop and freeing after the loop

Comment: @WeatherVane I am passing that substring to another function `fun(substr, , )`.

Comment: Well can you pass a pointer and the length?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am calculating the hamming distance between two strings of equal length. I am using a function `hd` (edited the question). I am not sure how to achieve that by passing pointer and length.

Comment: Surely in the same way as you do already, but without having to find its length within the function?

Comment: @WeatherVane would you mind telling me what changes I need to make in the code?

Comment: Your `hd` function appears to work on unsigned integers, not on strings.

Comment: @CPP_NEW How does XOR-ing two pointer values tell you anything meaningful about the strings they are pointing to?

Comment: @IanAbbott not sure what is happening internally, but it works for me

Comment: @IanAbbott You are right !! It does not work, I have two implementations of `hd` and the program was calling the other one instead of that inline function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By moving `malloc` and `free` outside of the loop makes the program much faster.

```
char str[] = "abcdcddcdcdcdcd....................." // large string
int n = strlen(str), m = 20;
char *substr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*m);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  //char *substr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*m);
  strncpy(substr, str+i, m);
  // do some processing
  int h = hd(substr, X) // X is another string of same length
  //free(substr); 
}
free(substr);

unsigned int hd(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{

    return std::inner_product(
        s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(),
        0, std::plus<unsigned int>(),
        std::not2(std::equal_to<std::string::value_type>())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps like this. It avoids multiple string handling, by passing the pointer of the current substring, and the length of the string to match.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int hd(char *str, char *cmp, int len)
// find hamming distance between substring *str and *cmp of length len
{
    int ind, hamming = 0;
    for(ind=0; ind<len; ind++) {
        if(str[ind] != cmp[ind]) {
            hamming++;
        }
    }
    return hamming;
}

int main(void)
// find hamming distance
{
    char str[] = "abcdcddcdcdcdcd";
    char cmp[] = "abc";
    int lens = strlen(str);
    int lenc = strlen(cmp);
    int ind, max;
    max = lens - lenc;
    // analyse each possible substring
    for(ind=0; ind<=max; ind++) {
        printf("%d\n", hd(str + ind, cmp, lenc));
    }
}
```

Comment: In my initial implementation I was using my own hamming distance function like the one you wrote. But I was passing two `char*` in my function. But use of `static inline int hd(unsigned x, unsigned y)` made it faster. I tried your approach and also my program with `malloc` before `for` loop but with `hd()` function The later program was faster.

Comment: You could `inline` this `hd` function too.

Comment: how could I do that? I believe that could make it faster.

Comment: You know how, because your question already does it. I was just showing how to do it without creating and destroying substrings.

Comment: got it , thanks !! It seems I read your comment too fast :)